# Laravel 5.2 all data reset when update 1 single data

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have table `dosen` and I want to update data to "statusdosen" column.

I have url : ...admin/dosen/status

When I click save, the page redirect to `..admin/dosen` and all data in that row has been reset (empty).

This is my view

```
{!! Form::model($value, ['route' => ['admin.dosen.update', $value->user_id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
  <br>
 {!! Form::select('statusdosen', array('1' => 'Dikampus', '0' => 'Tidak Dikampus'), null, ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Status'], ['class' => 'form-control']) !!} 
  <br><br>
 !! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Simpan', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'] )  !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Method :

```
 public function status()
{
    $dosen = Dosen::paginate(10);
    return view('admin/dosen.status', compact('dosen'));
}

public function update($id)

{
    $dosenUpdate = Request::only(['nipy', 'namadosen', 'alamatdosen', 'notelpdosen', 'tempatlahirdosen', 'tanggallahirdosen']);
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->dosen()->update($dosenUpdate);
    return redirect('admin/dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil diubah!');

}
```

what i want is after i click save it not redirect to other page. do i must create new update method data for 'statusdosen'?

Comment: Still not clear? Do you want to update single row or do you want to stay in same page after update?

Comment: @jonju yes i want update 1 data and stay in same page after update.

Comment: example : table dosen (iddosen, user_id, namadosen, address, statusdosen)

DSN01 | 12 | Adresss here | 1

i want update only 'statusdosen'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok that explains evreything

```
$user = User::find($id);
```

Actually this is same as

```
Update 
      dosen
Set
  Columnname1=$data, Columnnam2=data2
Where
     user_id = $id
```

This means all rows with this user_id will be updated.

You should be doing like below

```
public function update($id) { 
    $dosenUpdate = Request::only(['nipy', 'namadosen', 'alamatdosen', 'notelpdosen', 'tempatlahirdosen', 'tanggallahirdosen']);
     //$user= User::find($id); $user->dosen()->update($dosenUpdate);
    $dosen = dosen::find($id); // parameter $id must be id of the dosen you want to update
    $dosen->update(dosenUpdate);
    return back()->with('message', 'Data berhasil diubah!');
}
```

The `return back()` will take you back to the previous page but all input value will not be there as the page is being reloaded.

If you do want to keep the data you've two ways

1. Use `return back()->withInput()` and store the data to the corresponding input using `old`.
2. Use AJAX, and return a response as json.

   Eg:

   `return response()->json(['message'=>'Data berhasil diubah!');`

Comment: got error Call to a member function update() on null

Comment: I assumed the model name ` dosen`. You must change it to real model  name and make sure `$id` param is the id often dosen model not user...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something along the line of this

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    // Make sure the value is true/1 or false/0
    $this->validate($request, ['statusDosen' => 'boolean']);

    // Retrieve only the status
    $statusDosen = $request->get('statusDosen');

    // Update user->dosen()
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->dosen()->update($statusDosen);

    // Redirect back to the page you came from with your message
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Data berhasil diubah!');
}
```

Comment: i've edit page for dosen table. namadosen, nipy, user_id, statusdosen, etc. and when i update the data. it succes, but when i edit statusdosen. all the data being reset.